# Elasticsearch : how to build custom geo aggregation?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a simple Elastic index, with one geo_point = one document.
The geo shape point is simply named `position`. Per document, there are also other attributes like associated timespan (start date, end date).

To print points on a map, while handling zoom, I use the following Java code server-side :

```java
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;
...

Integer zoom = ...; // ranging from 1 to 5
String geo_point_field_name = "position";

AggregationBuilder centroidAgg = AggregationBuilders
    .geoCentroid("geo_centroid_agg")
    .field(geo_point_field_name);

return AggregationBuilders
    .geohashGrid("geo_hashgrid_agg")
    .field(geo_point_field_name)
    .size(10000)
    .precision(zoom)
    .subAggregation(centroidAgg);
```

It works great.

However, the problem is that I have in my index a lot of data points with similar coordinates (geo_point).

I want to agregate point close to each other to a single point, and thus avoiding to draw on the map very similar points.

*Note that I can't pre-compute position agregations before producing the index, because the user must search points at runtime regarding different criteria, like time-span (date start, date end)*

**Questions :**

- It is possible to do that without creating a custom agregation ?
- If not, how to create a custom Geo agregation for Elastic ?

Thank you

Comment: If I understand well you would like to have a cluster representation instead of all the point when sufficiently close from one another ?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. And if possible de combine with geo_hashgrid_agg, in order to know which point are in which geohash area/zone

Comment: It would be possible to achieve this with the new [geo HEX grid aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohexgrid-aggregation.html).

Comment: @Val could you please elaborate as an answer ?

Comment: It's actually very similar to your geohash grid aggregation which will aggregate all points that are close to one another. I'm curious why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: It doesn't work because, with geocentroid, the total number of points returned includes those very position-similar points. With geohash grid, I end up with points in a certain hash, but the position-similar points are not "reduced". Which also have an impact on pagination